# Understanding preservation of angles

Tags: geometry

In page 131 of Tristam Needham's book "Visual Complex Analysis", he writes

"If we now apply a sufficiently smooth transformation to the curves, then image curves will again same possess same tangents at image of 'p', and so there will be a well defined angle between these image curves"

And then he goes on to speak conformal and non conformal mappings, but I find this strange, how does the acute angle between tangents change if the tangents are fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Consider three curves through the point $p\in{\mathbb R}^2$. Curves $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ have the same tangent line $\ell$ at the point $p$, and $\gamma_3$ has a tangent line $\ell'\ne\ell$ at the point $p$. We now map a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ one-one and sufficiently smooth to a neighborhood $V$ of the point $q:=f(p)$. The image curves $f(\gamma_i)$ will then pass through the point $q$ and have tangents there. The tangents to $f(\gamma_1)$ and $f(\gamma_2)$ at $q$ will  coincide in the same line $t$, and the tangent to $f(\gamma_3)$ will be a line $t'\ne t$ through $q$. The angles $\angle(\ell,\ell')$ and $\angle(t,t')$ will  in general be different.

[image]

All this can be explained in terms of the differential map $df(p)$, which is a nonsingular map $T_p\to T_q$. We have linear dependent $\gamma_1'$, $\gamma_2'$ at $p$, whereas the tangent vector $\gamma_3'$ is linearly independent of the first two vectors. In the same way $df(p).\gamma_1'$ and $df(p).\gamma_2'\in T_q$ are linearly dependent, and $df(p).\gamma_3'$ is independent of these.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term "diffeomorphism", I searched on wiki but what exactly is the significance of it?

Comment: Could you please rephrase this answer for someone hasn't doesn't much topology? / explain the words a bit more